# Draw a png on another png in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, png, transparency

I'm making a rpg map creator in JS/Canvas for fun but I've a problem.
I can draw images on my canvas but I can't draw an image with transparency on another image already drawn on the canvas.

I would like the mushroom to be on the grass, not erase it. The grid is just a helper, I have only 1 canvas and I draw my mushroom using `putImageData`.

http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_31288520120419113247.png (we can see that the mushroom image has transparency)

http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_71357220120419113257.png (seems not working here)

I've you have any ideas, they are welcome.

Comment: the mushroom image you uploaded has no transparency...

Comment: the grey background is the container's background (that contains the canvas), so you can see that the mushroom has tranparency no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use putImageData as it will replace the pixels, use

```
context.drawImage(document.getElementById('mushroomImg'),0,0 );
//syntax : drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
```

JSFiddle with two images : 
http://jsfiddle.net/GVPfj/3/

( sadly, I couldn't find a mushroom with transparency, so it is a house :-) )

Comment: Well i used drawImage before using putImageData but didn't test that case, so time to go back :)

Comment: And i don't mind if you used a house, but next time, use a mushroom :D